# Is there any way to persist the entity having multiple map elements at one go?

Tags: java, jpa, collections, persist

I am trying to find ways to reduce the code repetition. Like this code I have multiple Map elements in my class. Please suggest me if you have something..!

```
public Class MyObject{
private Map map1;
private Map map2;
private Map map3;

//having setter/getter
}

importDatabase(){
//here i have data in the map1, map2, map3 elements
 importMap(MyObject.getMap1());
importMap(MyObject.getMap2());
importMap(MyObject.getMap3());
}

importMap(Map map){
//want to insert map objects into database at one go, instead of creating 3 methods for each type
Iterator iterator = map.values().iterator;
while(iterator.hasNext(){
}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the SO guidelines for posting a question.

Comment: @Pramod yes i will.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many similar object of the same type (*maps* in your case) and perform the same operations on all of them (put them in a database), a simple and usually viable way to avoid repetition is to store them in an *array* or in an *ArrayList* (if you don't know how many they are in advance) and perform the operations in a *for* or *foreach* loop.

With three elements it isn't always worth the effort and can actually make the code less readable than before. This will only make your code shorter and not improve performance (I assumed this is what you meant with *at one go*).

Comment: I have 10 such map elements in my class which is related to different entities and I want to create 1 method to persist those entities in db rather than creating 10 differenet methods for each map element